# How can I save an array to a specific memory location?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I declare my array as:

```
lettersArray db 'a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f','$';
```

But I want to save my array to a specific memory location. Is there any way to do such a thing?

Comment: What output format are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by output format ? (I'm pretty new to assembly)

Comment: It is a DOS program? A Windows program? A bootloader?

Comment: It's a x86 platform (I think a DOS program)

Comment: To answer the question _But I want to save my array to a specific memory location._ : Write a simple loop to copy the array to the destination, or use [_MOVSB_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html) to copy it? My apprehension with the question is that the title asks a slightly different question about _DECLARING_.

Comment: You are right , I edited the title.
And I think i'll use your idea and just loop it into memory